# How to extract a dynamic part or word from a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, qml

I am currently trying to figure out a method where I can extract a dynamic part of string when received via a message which is stored in variable. The variable receives a stock price from a web service in string format and I want to extract only the symbol in the example below: ARTL to pass to my QML text element. As the user query changes the symbol can also differ it could be GGOOG or anything.  I have tried using this `strmessage.indexOf("symbol") + 1` or + 2 but I don't seem to be getting the string value I want.

```
strmessage = "With ticker symbol ARTL, the current price is 115"
symbolname = strmessage.substring(strmessage.indexOf("symbol") + 1)
console.log(symbolname)
```

Please help with some example or regex reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression which searches for the string `'symbol'` and takes only the consecutive upper letters after.

```js
var strmessage = "With ticker symbol ARTL, the current price is 115",
    symbol = strmessage.match(/symbol ([A-Z]+)/)[1];

console.log(symbol);
```